# When does a wxPython modeless frame created at the local scope get actually destroyed?

Tags: wxpython

I have a `wxPython` application in which I bound one `wx.EVT_MENU` event on my main frame to a callback that pops up a child `wxFrame` (I want the popped up window to be modeless whence the use of a `wxFrame` in that case). My callback looks like:

```
def on_open_my_frame(self,event):
    local_frame = MyFrame(self)
    local_frame.Show()
```

This code is functional in the sense that the event actually pops up a frame I can interact with. However, I am a bit surprised that it works. Indeed, due to the very nature of my modeless frame I would expect the garbage collector to act upon my `local_frame` once out of the scope of `on_open_my_frame` method. Is that code valid ? Or in other words is there some kind of mechanism in `wxPython` that prevents a window to get destroyed until it is displayed ?

Comment: I would assume that it isn't garbage collected because it becomes a child of 'self' and therefore maintains the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI frameworks work a bit differently then other applications in that they are event based where the event loop runs continuously. Thus when you start up a frame and show it, the frame just hangs around waiting for the user to do something with it. In other words, the widgets you create wait for the user to interact with them, thus generating an event.

The only way for the frame to exit is if you tell the `frame` instance you created to explicitly `Close()` or `Destroy()` itself. Otherwise the frame will wait for the user to close it or interact with it in some other manner.